# linux ip route via 2 gateways, 3 interfaces

Tags: linux, routing, iproute2

I have 3 interfaces. I'll replace the public ips with 10.x.x.x.
eth0:

```
ips: 10.1.1.64-10.1.1.70
mask: 255.255.255.0
gateway: 10.1.1.1
ip route table: gw1a
```

eth1:

```
ip: 10.1.1.71
mask: 255.255.255.0
gateway: 10.1.1.1
ip route table: gw1b
```

eth2

```
ip: 10.2.2.135
mask:255.255.255.192
gateway: 10.2.2.129
ip route table: gw2
```

eth3 - will be used in rare cases. down most of the time. used to setup others

```
ip: 192.168.51.69
netmask: 255.255.255.0
gateway: 192.168.51.254
ip route table: office
```

While I'm setting the server up I'm connecting from 192.168.51.50.

I've made following script to set up routes. I need packets to go out using the interface they cam in from. The default gateway in main table is currently 192.168.51.254. I'll change it later to the gateway of eth0. When I run the script - I loose connection with the server. Why? Are packets that need to go to pc I'm connecting from 192.168.51.50 routed incorrectly? Are my ip route rules/routes correct. I'm not a network guru...

```
#!/bin/bash


ip=/sbin/ip

$ip rule show | grep -Ev '^(0|32766|32767):' | while read PRIO RULE; do
  echo "Removing rule prio ${PRIO%%:*} $RULE"
  $ip rule del prio ${PRIO%%:*}
done

$ip route flush table gw1a >/dev/null 1>&2
$ip route flush table gw1b >/dev/null 1>&2
$ip route flush table gw2 >/dev/null 1>&2
$ip route flush table office >/dev/null 1>&2

$ip route add default via 10.1.1.1 table gw1a dev eth0
$ip route add default via 10.1.1.1 table gw1b dev eth1
$ip route add default via 10.2.2.129 table gw2 dev eth2
$ip route add default via 192.168.51.254 table office dev eth3

for i in `/usr/bin/seq 65 70` ; do
  echo "rule from 10.1.1.$i -> gw1a"
  $ip rule add from 10.1.1.$i table gw1a
done

echo "rule from 10.1.1.71 -> gw1b"
$ip rule add from 10.1.1.71 table gw1b

echo "rule from 10.2.2.135 -> gw2"
$ip rule add from 10.2.2.135 table gw2

echo "rule from 192.168.51.69 -> office"
```

Comment: What is your default gw in the main table?

Comment: 10.1.1.1 is not reachable via eth1, so it can't be the gateway for that interface.

Answer (score 0):

Solved!
I've added local networks (accessible directly, without gateway) to gw1a, gw1b, gw2 and office tables:

```
ip route add src 10.1.1.64 10.1.1.0/24 proto kernel scope link table gw1a dev eth0
ip route add src 10.1.1.71 10.1.1.0/24 proto kernel scope link table gw1b dev eth1
ip route add src 10.2.2.135 10.2.2.128/26 proto kernel scope link table gw2 dev eth2
ip route add src 192.168.51.69 192.168.51.0/24 proto kernel scope link table office dev eth3
```

I saw it like this in main table, so I added it to all other tables.

I'll wait for comments before I accept this as answer. I have the feeling there is a better way...

Comment: General remark about multi-homing: expect problems specifically for UDP services hosted on this system. Better don't run any or they have to be multi-homed aware following one of two methods: always bind to each and every IP address for every IP address available (eg: the DNS server bind 9 does this) or always use the IP_PKTINFO socket option (eg: the DNS server unbound does this).